# How divide result from text field to label and get it on another label

Tags: swift, xcode, division, divide-by-zero

I need to finish(Label) = totalAmount(TextField) / adam (Label).
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
var plusAndMinus = 0

class ViewController234: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var adam: UILabel!

@IBAction func plus(_ sender: Any) {
    plusAndMinus += 1
   adam.text = "\(plusAndMinus)"
}

@IBAction func minus(_ sender: Any) {
    if(plusAndMinus != 0 ) {
        plusAndMinus -= 1
    }
   adam.text = "\(plusAndMinus)"
}

// Write total amonunt to calculate

@IBOutlet weak var totalAmount: UITextField!

@IBAction func equal(_ sender: Any) {
  
    var adam = 0
    var totalAmount = 0
    var result = 0
    adam = Int(adam)
    totalAmount = Int(totalAmount)
    guard result != 0 else {return}
   
    result = totalAmount / adam
    finish.text = String(result)
}

//Show calculated
// finish = totalAmount / adam

@IBOutlet weak var finish: UILabel!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are only accessing your local variables and not the text fields in the `equal()` function.

It is better to use different names for local variables and class properties to avoid confusion.

So first lets validate that the text fields contains values that can be converted to Int variables and otherwise return directly by using `guard`. Then it's simply a matter of dividing the values but of course we also want to avoid decision by zero so we check that to

```
@IBAction func equal(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let text = Adam.text, let adamValue = Int(text), adamValue != 0,
          let totalAmountValue = Int(totalAmount.text!) else { return }

    let result = totalAmountValue / adamValue
    finish.text = String(result)
}
```

By using integers we are doing integer division and thus loosing precision, if you want to keep the precision you can switch to Double in the code above and perhaps add some formatting of the result

```
@IBAction func equal(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let text = Adam.text, let adamValue = Double(text), adamValue != 0,
          let totalAmountValue = Double(totalAmount.text!) else { return }

    let result = totalAmountValue / adamValue
    finish.text = String(format: "%.2f", result)
}
```

Comment: It is again give me the same error: "Initializer 'init(_:radix:)' requires that 'UILabel' conform to 'StringProtocol'" and "IInitializer 'init(_:radix:)' requires that 'UITextField' conform to 'StringProtocol'l"

Comment: the code that you right to me give an error. Sorry for disturbing. I ask another question, i am new here , don't know how site works. Thank u for your time.

Comment: Is it finish.text that give the error? I don't understand where `init(:radix:)` comes from since it isn't part of my code.

Comment: in this 2 lines Xcode give error: " guard let adamValue = Double(adam), adamValue != 0,
          let totalAmountValue = Double(totalAmount) else { return }"

Comment: Ok, I forgot to change some things from the code I wrote in the playground. I update the answer

Comment: Now it gives another error on line "guard let adamValue..." => "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Have you checked that your text fields and labels are properly connected in your storyboard?

Comment: I noticed now that `adam` is a label and not a textfield as I thought so it need to be handled differently. I update my answer

Comment: To tell you truth no. I decided to change text field and add button like on calculator. Thank you for help.

Comment: Then you shouldn’t mark my answer as accepted but instead delete the question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `finish` label is because you don't have a label for it, but given that you're meaning to output your answer to it:

```swift
enum InputError: Error {
    case emptyAdamLabel
    case emptyTotalAmountLabel
    case divideByZero
    case invalidFormat
}

func calculate() throws {
    if let adamText = adam.text, adamText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
        throw InputError.emptyAdamLabel
    } else if let total = totalAmount.text, total.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
        throw InputError.emptyTotalAmountLabel
    } else if let adamText = adam.text, adamText == "0" {
        throw InputError.divideByZero
    } else if let adamNumber = Double(adam.text!), let totalAmountNumber = Double(totalAmount.text!) {
        finish.text = String(format: "%.2f", totalAmountNumber / adamNumber)
    } else {
        throw InputError.invalidFormat
    }
}

@IBAction func equal(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        try calculate()
    } catch InputError.emptyAdamLabel {
        print("Adam's label cannot be empty")
    } catch InputError.emptyTotalAmountLabel {
        print("Total Amount's label cannot be empty")
    } catch InputError.divideByZero {
        print("Adam's label cannot be zero")
    } catch InputError.invalidFormat {
        print("Both Adam's label and Total Amount's label have to be integers")
    } catch {
        print("Unknown errors")
    }
    adam.text = "0"
    totalAmount.text = "0"
}
```

Comment: finish(label) in the end of code. Thank you for your time. It is not exactly what i need